# How to convert a microsecond timestamp to milliseconds in Kafka connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

While populating BigQuery from Kafka using [confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/), I'd like to use the timestamp of our domain (Avro) events to (day-) partition the tables.

My `connector.properties` looks as follows:

```
[...]
transforms=ConvertTimestamp
transforms.ConvertTimestamp.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.ConvertTimestamp.field=metadata_date
transforms.ConvertTimestamp.target.type=Timestamp

timestampPartitionFieldName=metadata_date
[...]
```

```
Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-522" com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException: table insertion failed for the following rows:
    [row index 0]: invalid: Timestamp field value is out of range:1597279521000000000
    [row index 1]: invalid: Timestamp field value is out of range:1597279523000000000
[...]
```

The issue seems to be, our timestamps are in microseconds (UTC Unix epoch)

```
"type": {
    "type": "long",
    "logicalType": "timestamp-micros"
}
```

while BigQuery wants milliseconds (or seconds?).

Is there a way to transform the timestamp directly using the connector?

Comment: Microseconds aren't typically the definition of Unix epoch. How much effort would it be to change the schema? `logicalType": "timestamp-millis"`

Comment: @OneCricketeer This would be way too much effort. It's used in all event types on all topics, produced and consumed by multiple services in different programming languages. And there is historical data for multiple years on the topics like that already. :/

Comment: I see. In that case, my only suggestion would be Kafka Streams/ksql for the conversion because I don't think there's any builtin transforms for this. The TimestampConverter is typically used for formatting, not unit conversion

Comment: @OneCricketeer Damn, I feared that. Thanks for the info nonetheless. I was hoping even if there is no arithmetic transformer, which could be used to divide the value by 1000, a string regex transformer would be good. Then I could do something like this: cast-microsecond-int-to-string -> crop-last-3-characters -> cast-to-int -> cast-to-timestamp

Comment: Unfortunately you'd also have to find/write that  substring transformer :)